# Is there a word for "grand" relatives except for parents?

Tags: word-request

Is it possible to call uncle or aunt "grand"? Do you have a word for grandparent's sisters and brothers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words you are looking for are "great-aunt" and "great-uncle", in US English. I have personally never heard "grand-aunt" and "grand-uncle", but apparently they are about 1/10th as common:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely add 'grand' and call them...

> A grandaunt or a granduncle

Not sure about other terms because in my mother tongue each of them has a different honorific!

Comment: In my family the aunts and uncles of my parents were called great-aunts, or great-uncles, despite the fact that if you think about it, this conflicts with the other family hierarchy words. It seems that this isn't unusual. https://blogs.ancestry.com/ancestry/2013/10/25/great-and-grand-aunts/

Comment: You asked grandparent's sisters and brothers so the answer is grandaunts and granduncles. Some use 'great' as well.

Comment: Hmm? I didn't ask anything. I'm just trying to offer some information that might be useful to the answer. There are multiple words for this relationship and it's probably a little confusing.

Comment: Aww...I meant the *OP* asked! :) @LeeV

Comment: I think @LeeV has hit the nail on the head. Technically it's 'grand', but no-one uses it. I didn't even know it was the correct term until I looked at that article. All my 'grands' were 'greats' & I'd never heard the term 'grand' used until this very question.